# Facebook and Google Plus integration in android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-activity, google-plus

I'm trying to integrate facebook and google plus login in my android app and they individually works pretty well.

When I try to integrate both of them at a time they dosent seem to work fine.

This is my structure flow:

1.LoginActivity---->Users clicks either google+ or facebook login button.

2. If the user authenticates then he will be moved to my MainActivity.

This is my LoginActivity:

```
public class GoogleLogin extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private boolean mIntentInProgress;

private boolean mSignInClicked;

private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

public static GoogleLogin mContext;

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

Button fbutton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mContext = this;

uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


setContentView(R.layout.login);
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.addApi(Plus.API, PlusOptions.builder().build())
.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
.build();


findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button
&& !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
mSignInClicked = true;
resolveSignInError();
}
}
});



fbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnflogin);

findViewById(R.id.btnflogin).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(GoogleLogin.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      // callback when session changes state
      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {

          // make request to the /me API
          Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {


                  Intent i = new Intent(GoogleLogin.this,MainActivity.class);


                    //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
                    i.putExtra("Facebook", "Logged in using Facebook Account");
                    i.putExtra("LastName", user.getLastName());
                    i.putExtra("FirstName", user.getFirstName());
                    //Add the bundle to the intent
                    i.putExtras(i);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
               }
            }
          }).executeAsync();
        }
      }
    });


}
});

}


private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {

            Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session opened");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {

            Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session closed");
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
}



private void resolveSignInError() {
if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
try {
mIntentInProgress = true;
startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
} catch (SendIntentException e) {
// The intent was canceled before it was sent. Return to the default
// state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
mIntentInProgress = false;
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
}
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);

if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
mSignInClicked = false;
}

mIntentInProgress = false;

if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
}

}

protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
}

public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
if (!mIntentInProgress) {
// Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
// 'sign-in'.
mConnectionResult = result;

if (mSignInClicked) {
// The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
// errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
resolveSignInError();
}
}
}

public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
// We've resolved any connection errors. mGoogleApiClient can be used to
// access Google APIs on behalf of the user.
mSignInClicked = false;
Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

//Create the bundle
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
bundle.putString("Google", "Logged in using Google Account");
bundle.putString("GoogleUsername",  currentPerson.getDisplayName());
//Add the bundle to the intent
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);

}

}

public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {

mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

public void gplusSignout(View v){
//if (v.getId() == R.id.gPlusSignout) {
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
//mGoogleApiClient.connect();
Log.d("Debug","Disconnected");
Toast.makeText(this, "User is disconnected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
//}
}


}
```

These are bit confusing me :

```
private void resolveSignInError() {
if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
try {
mIntentInProgress = true;
startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
} catch (SendIntentException e) {
// The intent was canceled before it was sent. Return to the default
// state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
mIntentInProgress = false;
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
}
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {

if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
mSignInClicked = false;
}

mIntentInProgress = false;

if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
}

}

protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
}

public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
if (!mIntentInProgress) {
// Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
// 'sign-in'.
mConnectionResult = result;

if (mSignInClicked) {
// The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
// errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
resolveSignInError();
}
}
}
```

I'm struck at this point where I'm not sure can I do this way in ActivityResult:

To startup Facebook and move to the next activity this works fine:

```
@Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

But at the same time I have google+ onActivity result..So how do I manage both of them ?

Can anyone say me how do I acheive this in order to get both of them working.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? How do you handle login on other activities?

Comment: @MiteshSharma Have you solved it?

Comment: I authenticate user on client side, then save on client that user is authenticated by saving one bit. And send user details on server which was fetched from fb/google. Now when user clears DB, then this bit is gone, so take him to auth page or else main page. Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you completely. Have you a working sample code of both integration in same activity?